# how to change space between JFrame and JLabel in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Layout is `FreeDesign`

I want to make less space between `JLabel` and `JFrame` in NetBeans GUI editor.
But I can't because when I change `JLabel` size it sticks to `JFrame` border, so in this case there is no any space between them.

[image]

When I hold `alt` key and change `JLabel` size, `JFrame` size is increasing automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- add [EmptyBorders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) to the expected [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
- [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) haven't got Borders
- [Standard LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and `Customer LayoutManagers` don't suffer from similar limitations as placing prepared Components from palette,
- you can change built_in LayoutManager in the project properties, I assume that with similair limitations for possitioning Components by mouse dragging, use built_in GridBagLayout